# conditional probability of 3 events into 2 conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Consider: $$P(A,B |D)$$

Now I consider $C_i$ such that: $\cup_i C_i = \Omega $

This leads to: $$P(A,B |D) = \sum_iP(A,B,C_i |D)= \sum_iP( A,B,C_i,D) P(D) $$

Is there any way to rewrite the right side in a product of two conditional probabilitys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NB:** You also require the sequence to be pairwise disjoint: $\forall i~\forall j~(i\neq j\to C_i\cap C_j=\emptyset)$

Then, by the Law of Total Probability, you will have:

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A,B\mid D)&=\sum_i\mathsf P(A,B,C_i\mid D)\\[1ex]&=\sum_i\left(\mathsf P(A,B,C_i,D)\,\middle/\,\mathsf P(D)\right)\\[1ex]&=\sum_i\left(\mathsf P(A,B\mid C_i,D)\,\mathsf P(C_i,D)\,\middle/\,\mathsf P(D)\right)\\[1ex]&=\sum_i\mathsf P(A,B\mid C_i,D)\,\mathsf P(C_i\mid D)\end{align}$

Comment: In the third line you consider $Q:=A \cap B$ and $P:=C \cap D| $ isn't it?

Comment: Yes.  The comma in the list of events of probability functions is read as a conjunction.

Comment: Thank you very much:)